# ionic header bar hiding input label

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I am using an ionic header bar in my app... When I click on an input label to enter some text... you can't see the input bar anymore... When I click on a selector, the header bar will disappear... Is there a way to make it do this for inputs?

Previously, the input distance was above the "from" selector list.. I placed it below, but this didn't help fix it. Also, it looks fine on iPhone 6... It just gets worse on smaller screens.

Pictures below:

[image: Normal looking]

[image: Can't see distance input value]

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/page/keyboard/) what you're looking for?

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true)
```

Comment: This looks like what I am looking for... Sorry kinda a noob.. Where do I put this?

Comment: I just put it .in run on `$ionicPlatform.ready(function(){})`

Comment: i've tried this and i am still seeing the 2nd image above

Comment: Hmm, may be a pain of a process, but can you create a starter app with use just the template above, and recreate the issue?